# Using oauth_token and oauth_token_secret how to get user details with twitter api?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a oauth_token and oauth_token_secret. Is there any way to get twitter user details using this? I have a twitter button in my website and after successful login i got oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve quite a bit of information about users from the API.

Visit (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) and scroll down to the "Users" section.  It details the calls you can make and what information is returned by each.